# Avoid multiple error notifications when API responds with 401 on expired session

Tags: react-admin

My custom react-admin page has a component that makes several API calls. When session expired and all calls respond with 401 status, I'm redirected to login, but the notification appears multiple times (once for each failed call).

The calls are made using specialised hooks.

Is there a way to silence those notifications? Looking through react-admin code, I don't think it's possible. It seems that the only option is to resolve the promise in `authProvider.checkError` and handle the errors elsewhere (not sure how, yet).

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Thinking out loud! Are your API calls synchronous or asynchronous? If the former (sync), then first check the first call before you do the next call. If the latter (async), as i suspect, then it's best left as is. Because you want to make sure a user gets some feedback after a call, success or failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The calls are async. I agree with the feedback for the user, but I could use more control on the notifications.

Comment: My assumption is that you are already using the `useNotify` within your API calls, right? If so (like i expect), then don't just look out for an  error but look out for the status too. And of particular interest for you would be the `401 Error`. Since a user is redirected to login, you could avoid notifying in this case. It's really an issue of user experience vs what's expected.

Comment: I don't use useNotify. I catch 401 status in authProvider.checkError and reject the Promise. In that case, react-admin automatically logs the user out and displays the notification. I tried defining an onFailure callback, but the logging out happens before that and the callback is not executed.